# MVC5 App redirects to login.aspx when calling secured actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-7, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

i have created a new ASP.NET MVC 5.1 Web App with VS 2013. In my local IIS Express all is working fine. One controller is decorated with an Authorize-Attribute. When i open a secured action in this controller without logging in before this, i was correctly redirected to the login page (/Account/Login). But in my productive IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008) the server redirects my to login.aspx.

Could this occure while i use OWIN Middleware and the old IIS 7.0 can#t work with it? In the bin dir there are all the OWIN-dlls from my project.

There are alos problem with the rediretion process while i use an external login provider like Google. Same procedure like above. :-(

Does anybody have some hints for me?

Thanks.
Andreas

Comment: Did you set the `login.aspx` as the startup page?

Comment: Your so right. In the FormsAuthentication settings were the wrong login path. I think, this causes from the slightly different web.config in the new template. There are no settings for forms auth. After replacing the login.aspx with ~/Account/Login all works very well. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please answer the question? With the correction, supply the code?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup and same problem too: instead of redirecting to /account/login or whatever login path you set up in CookieAuthenticationOptions, it always redirects to /login.aspx.

One workaround is, after you publish **EVERY SINGLE TIME**, you need to go in IIS, select the project, hit Authentication and disable the default Form Authentication.

If you select the form authentication and hit edit, you will see /login.aspx default route is there.

By the way, adding these 2 AppSettings won't fix it:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution : Go to IIS -> select your project -> Double tap on authentication
-> select forms authentication -> edit and set your default login redirect url .
This is where the login.aspx is hardcoded . This is configurable and changed based on project routes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same The solution which worked with is the following:
in IIS, go to Authentication, set authnentication by Form to False